# Database Concurrency Problems

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm currently developing a database/website server interface to facilitate inputting data for a data collection project. There are two types of additions being made to the database: A and B here. Some of the tables in the database that handle these entries are as follows:

dcs_projectname_a

dcs_projectname_b

Each of these have tables for all the required input fields in addition to things like creator, timestamp, etc.

The pages on the website facilitate three different options: add, view, and edit. Each page for each type of entry performs the respective function. That is, the add page adds, view page views, etc.

I am just about done; however, there is a major challenge I haven't really confronted yet: concurrency. There will be multiple users adding content to the database at the same time. Each entry is given its own specific id and there CANNOT be any duplicate id's. That is, the first a entry is A000001, the next is A000002, and so on.

On the add and edit pages, there is a disabled field for the user to view the id for other uses when physically documenting entries.

What I need to figure out is how to implement concurrency management so that when users are concurrently adding a's that they will not be under the same id and row.

The add page automatically generates the id to be used by accessing the database's most recent id and adding one.

My thought was to create a new row in the table every time the add page is opened and give it the calculated id. Then, when information is added it performs a modification to that existing row. This way, if another user opens the add page while another entry is currently being added it will be given the future id, not the same one.

With this method I need a way to delete this entry if the user leaves the add page or closes the browser. Then, I also need other users with open add pages to automatically update their id's to one less when the first user (or any other user less than the most id being used) leaves their add page and cancels the addition.

This is kind of a complicated explanation and if you don't understand let me know and I'll try to answer as best as I can. Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of solutions to your problem, but you seem to have made things harder by having your application generate the record IDs for you.

Instead, you could just be using MySQL's [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html) functionality to automatically generate/increment the record ID for you (upon insert). MySQL will ensure that there are no duplicates, and you can get rid of the extra database call to retrieve the most recent ID.

Comment: True, however, I have used AUTO_INCREMENT for a separate field called "database_id". The reason I use the database call is to fill the id field with an alphanumeric id that the user can see while entering the other information for that entry.

Comment: Does it have to be a sequential value as your described? Otherwise you could just generate a UUID. If it has to be sequential, I can't think of an easy solution. The easiest would be to add a unique constraint on the column, and if the insert fails due to a constraint violation, try again with the next value. If your application is under heavy load, this will become inefficient very fast.